# Not able to import python class in C#

Tags: python

I'm calling a python class called nump from C#. Calling the class works, but I think there may be something wrong with my spacing. Please see the example below:

```
class nump
   def nump():
      import numpy as np
      incomes = np.random.normal(27000, 15000, 10000)
      np.mean(incomes)
         return np
```

I cntiniously get a newline error.

Please any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your `return` line is not properly indented. Also your `class` line is missing a colon.

Comment: Could you add the full error stacktrace? It is a bit hard to guess what exactly is wrong without more info.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "newline error". Please post the actual error message.

Answer (score 1):

Align the return statement, it's not properly indented.

```
import numpy as np
class Nump:
   def nump(self):
      incomes = np.random.normal(27000, 15000, 10000)
      return np.mean(incomes)
```

Comment: missing `self` my friend in `nump()` @Rahul Hastu also you class name is not according to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and do not return 'np' module it is meaningless return `np.mean(incomes)` did the edit

Answer (score 0):

edited code which works.

```
import numpy as np

class Nump:
   def meanIncomes(self):
      incomes = np.random.normal(27000, 15000, 10000)
      return np.mean(incomes)

num = Nump()
print(num.meanIncomes())
```

you need a `self` argument in all functions of a class.

`np.mean(incomes)` does not turn `np` into the mean incomes so you would need to `return mp.mean(incomes)`

Answer (score 0):

First keep import statement at top then you should create a class like this
good practice is to inherit from `object` class. For python 2 3 compatibility or what you have done is also fine

Then please keep classname according to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

You should pass `self` as first argument to make it work if your function is not taking argument. `self` references to the very object.

You should not return `np` instead return result `np.mean(incomes)`

```
import numpy as np

class Nump(object):
   def nump(self):
      incomes = np.random.normal(27000, 15000, 10000)
      return np.mean(incomes)
```

At C# side

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile( @"filepath"); #python file path here 
dynamic nump_obj = py.Nump();
```